# d3 network diagram window boundries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, diagram

I have a simple network diagram. It contains of circle elements and lines connecting them. Now sometimes there could be quite a lot of those circles and they go 'behind' the screen (see the image attached).
The image doesnt cut off the edges, its the edge of my screen :)

Its a force diagram (code used can be found in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/95/) ). Setting the `width = 400;
  height = 500;` or changing these two variables doesn't really help.
What variable am I missing here. Id like them not to go 'behind' the screen or is it just how it should behave ?

Thanks,
Neil

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/114/)

```
map.set('C1', {
    fixed: true,
    x: 100,
    y: height / 2
  });
```

problem is that your 'C1' is fixed at 100 in x axis change it to 200 or 250 according to your need

```
map.set('C1', {
        fixed: true,
        x: 250,
        y: height / 2
      });
```

OR

you can change `fixed: false,` to achieve the same [**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/115/)

```
map.set('C1', {
    fixed: false,
    x: 100,
    y: height / 2
  });
```

OR

set C1 width half [**DEMO3**](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/116/)

```
map.set('C1', {
    fixed: true,
    x: width/2,
    y: height / 2
  });
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for Your time. But what if the diagram gets bigger both sides - then moving the C1 doesnt really help. Im more looking how to contain all the circles in some sort of container, of course if its possible

Comment: fixed: false, will set your diagram automatically in given space

Comment: Thanks, But I do need that center circle to be fixed. I understand what Your saying, but the purpose of this to show circles on the left and on the right gathered around one center one

Comment: set x with half width

Comment: Right, so that places the center circle in the middle, but as You see in my attached picture when theres a lot of connections they still go beyond the 'screen'

Comment: then the only way is to set the position of c1 such as all L can be in the frame